# OpenSource project with lots of WCF?

Tags: wcf

Is there any big open source application which heavily uses WCF or old asmx services? I discovered just MS samples: Stock Trader and CardSpace, then some: Chats on Codeplex and Multiplayer quiz.

Comment: I don't think so. WCF does not really fit in the kind of apps OSS usually produces, plus there are better options usually used in OSS than WCF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing one. WCF is awesome and there is no better alternative in Mono for example.